# how to create array into array in codignitor

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I create an API for collection-category.but I face a problem with making an array into an array.

I already try to unset old array and append into a new array but I have not come proper array.

My collection table looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `crm_collection` (
 `collection_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `heading` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `collection_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` enum('Active','In-active') DEFAULT NULL,
 `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`collection_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 insert  into   `crm_collection`(`collection_id`,`heading`,`collection_image`,`status`,`group_id`) values (33,'test3','30d79a495652f762bbe365df59dbef3b.jpeg','Active',1),(34,'test4','7cc28028d0684d9bb58e285434002758.jpeg','In-active',3);
```

My collection-category table looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `crm_category_collection` (
  `category_collection_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','In-active') DEFAULT NULL,
  `collection_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_collection_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `crm_category_collection`(`category_collection_id`,`text`,`category_image`,`status`,`collection_id`,`category_id`) values (61,'testerrrdsfdsf','b80314b0d1235ced3fef2b5ef55ff2d2download-(5).jpeg',NULL,33,3),(62,'testw','c3dd2c871fcb4f87f416473a45aedabedownload-(5).jpeg',NULL,33,11),(63,'test78','22278fa17bf50da7b9ec408114d6b092download-(4).jpeg',NULL,33,12);
```

This is my API code.

```
$table_collection = "crm_collection";
     $table_collection_id = 'tl.collection_id';
     $default_sort_column_collection = 'tl.collection_id';
     $default_sort_order_collection = 'desc';
     $condition_collection = "1=1";

    $main_table_collection = array("$table_collection tl", array("tl.collection_id", "tl.heading", "tl.collection_image", "tl.group_id"));
    $join_tables_collection = array(
        array("left", "tbl_menu tm", "tm.id = tl.group_id", array("tm.menu_name as group_name","tm.id as group_id")),
        array("left", "crm_category_collection cc", "cc.collection_id = tl.collection_id", array("cc.text","cc.category_image","cc.category_id")),
    );

    $rs = $this->apis_model->JoinFetch($main_table_collection, $join_tables_collection, $condition_collection, array($default_sort_column_collection => $default_sort_order_collection)); // fetch query
    $collection_data = $this->apis_model->MySqlFetchRow($rs, "array"); // fetch result

    if (empty($collection_data)) {
        $collection_data = array();
    } else {
        foreach ($collection_data as $key => $val) {
            unset($collection_data[$key]);
            $temp=array();
            $collection_data[$key]['heading']=$val['heading'];
            $collection_data[$key]['group_id']=$val['group_id'];
            $collection_data[$key]['group_name']=$val['group_name'];
            $temp['text']=$val['text'];
            $temp['category_id']=$val['category_id'];

            if (!empty($val['collection_image']) && $val['collection_image'] != "") {
                $collection_image = "";
                $collection_image = base_url() . "images/collections/" . $val['collection_image'];
                //echo $icon_image; exit;
                $collection_data[$key]['collection_image'] = $collection_image;
            }
            if (!empty($val['category_image']) && $val['category_image'] != "") {
                $category_image = "";
                $category_image = base_url() . "images/collections/" . $val['category_image'];
                //echo $category_image; exit;
                $temp['category_image'] = $category_image;
                $collection_data[$key]['category'][] = $temp;

        // print_r($collection_data);
            }
        }
        // exit();
    }
    $result['collection'] = $collection_data;
```

And this result will come to this type.

```
"collection-category": [
{
  "heading": "test3",
  "group_id": "1",
  "group_name": "group1",
  "collection_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/30d79a495652f762bbe365df59dbef3b.jpeg",
  "category": [
    {
      "collection_id": "33",
      "text": "dfsfdsfd",
      "category_id": "11",
      "category_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/219cbf9b9bdd8f6581801310dd312ef5download-(6).jpeg"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "heading": "test3",
  "group_id": "1",
  "group_name": "group1",
  "collection_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/30d79a495652f762bbe365df59dbef3b.jpeg",
  "category": [
    {
      "collection_id": "33",
      "text": "testerrrdsfdsf",
      "category_id": "3",
      "category_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/b80314b0d1235ced3fef2b5ef55ff2d2download-(5).jpeg"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

But I have this type of result because my collection is one but in collection multiple categories include.

```
"collection-category": [
{
  "heading": "test3",
  "group_id": "1",
  "group_name": "group1",
  "collection_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/30d79a495652f762bbe365df59dbef3b.jpeg",
  "category": [
    {
      "collection_id": "33",
      "text": "hi",
      "category_id": "11",
      "category_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/219cbf9b9bdd8f6581801310dd312ef5download-(6).jpeg"
    },
    {
      "collection_id": "34",
      "text": "hello",
      "category_id": "3",
      "category_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/b80314b0d1235ced3fef2b5ef55ff2d2download-(5).jpeg"
    },
    {
      "collection_id": "35",
      "text": "teste123",
      "category_id": "3",
      "category_image": "http://localhost:8000/images/collections/b80314b0d1235ced3fef2b5ef55ff2d2download-(5).jpeg"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Please help me i can't understand how create this type of response.

Comment: It is better if you show the table schema for all those tables..

Comment: But how we send SQL  file. ?

Comment: add schema and dummy data with same question

Comment: okay, now check I will add tables with dummy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vaibhavi sikligar

Here the code describing that how the logic should run on your result set to get desired format with some dummy array data as matching like your query result.

```
$test = array( array( "collection_id" => 33, 'heading' => 'test3', 'category_id' => 3, 'text' => 'dfsfdsfd1' ),
    array( "collection_id" => 33, 'heading' => 'test3', 'category_id' => 4, 'text' => 'dfsfdsfd2' ),
    array( "collection_id" => 34, 'heading' => 'test4', 'category_id' => 5, 'text' => 'dfsfdsfd3' ),
    array( "collection_id" => 34, 'heading' => 'test4', 'category_id' => 6, 'text' => 'dfsfdsfd4' )
);

$res= array();

foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    if( !isset($res[$value['collection_id']]) ){
        $res[$value['collection_id']] = array();
        $res[$value['collection_id']]['collection_id'] = $value['collection_id'];
        $res[$value['collection_id']]['heading'] = $value['heading'];
    }           
    $colarr = isset($res[$value['collection_id']]['category']) && is_array($res[$value['collection_id']]['category']) ? $res[$value['collection_id']]['category'] : array(); 
    $colarr[] = array( 'category_id' => $value['category_id'], 'text' => $value['text'] );
    $res[$value['collection_id']]['category'] = $colarr;                    
}
$output = array();
$output['collection-category'] = array_values($res);
echo json_encode($output);
```

You can try this in your code.